# Draw an Arrow on a Picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I want to be able to draw a straight arrow from one mouse click location to another, as if you were doing it in PowerPoint. It needs to be able to draw on a PictureBox as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is some basic code to draw lines in a picturebox from mouse down to current location.
You just need to draw some more lines or a triangle for the arrow head.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool isMoving = false;
    private Point mouseDownPosition = Point.Empty;
    private Point mouseMovePosition = Point.Empty;
    private List<Tuple<Point, Point>> lines = new List<Tuple<Point, Point>>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(231, 235);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseDown);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseMove);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseUp);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        if (isMoving)
        {
            g.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, line.Item1, line.Item2);
            }
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        mouseDownPosition = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            mouseMovePosition = e.Location;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            lines.Add(Tuple.Create(mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition));
        }
        isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, just one thing is how do i make it so the arrow i have drawn stays there when i draw another arrow, because at the moment the last arrow drawn disappears when i start to draw a new one? How do i fix it so they stay? Thanks

Comment: @Chris Bacon, You store them in a list: `List<Tuple<Point, Point>> points = new List<Tuple<Point, Point>>();`, add them to the list in MouseUp: `points.Add(Tuple.Create(mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition));` and draw them in a foreach loop in pictureBox1_Paint.

Comment: Can you please edit your code above with this code to make the arrows stay there please, Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**It's easy to draw arrows in the same way that you worked out how to draw lines on a `PictureBox` in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187524/draw-lines-on-a-picturebox-in-c).**

All you have to do is specify a `StartCap` or `EndCap` for the `Pen` object you are already using to draw lines. Intuitively, the [`StartCap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.startcap(v=VS.100).aspx) property allows you to specify a cap style that is used at the beginning of any lines you draw with the `Pen` object, while the [`EndCap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.endcap(v=VS.100).aspx) property allows you to specify a cap style for the end of the lines.

Several different [`LineCap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.linecap.aspx) styles are available, including:

```
Flat          Specifies a flat line cap.
Square        Specifies a square line cap.
Round         Specifies a round line cap.
Triangle      Specifies a triangular line cap.
NoAnchor      Specifies no anchor.
SquareAnchor  Specifies a square anchor line cap.
RoundAnchor   Specifies a round anchor cap.
DiamondAnchor Specifies a diamond anchor cap.
ArrowAnchor   Specifies an arrow-shaped anchor cap.
Custom        Specifies a custom line cap.
AnchorMask    Specifies a mask used to check whether a line cap is an anchor cap.
```

You will probably find the `ArrowAnchor` style most useful in this case: **just specify an `ArrowAnchor` as the `LineCap` style for either the start or end of the line (depending on the direction in which you want the arrow to point).**

The following code will draw a green, right-facing arrow with a line thickness of 4:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
 //Create a new pen to draw the arrow with
 using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Green, 4f))
 {
  //Specify the EndCap, because we're drawing a right-facing arrow
  p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;

  //Draw the arrow
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, 30, 45);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with reference to **Albin Sunnanbo** answer that was great stuff

If you want to **draw arrow** just replace

```
 g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition);
```

to

```
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black,3);
p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
g.DrawLine(p, mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition);
p.Dispose();
```