# Stuck at using drawing line and making it stay

Tags: c#

I am new to C# world so I am currently facing some problem now.
I used window form C# and tried to draw lines on picturebox.
However, now my coding only allows me to draw one single line.
When I tried to draw another line, the previous line just disappear.
I tried to search online for help but nothing seems to work. 
Please help me out guys! This is my coding so far.

```
public partial class  Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int startX, startY, endX, endY;
    Graphics g;
    int draw = 0;


    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            draw = 1;             
            startX = e.X;
            startY = e.Y;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(startX,startY), new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        endX = e.X;
        endY = e.Y;
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(startX, startY), new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        draw = 0;   
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can either store a sequence of drawing commands and re-execute them on every window repaint, or you can paint a backing buffer bitmap and blit (copy+paste) that bitmap data to the window's surface when the window is repainted.

Comment: You can only draw in the paint event. Anything you draw outside that event will be replaced when the paint event occurs, as you've already seen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255614/draw-an-arrow-on-a-picturebox-in-c-sharp

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is also the wrong thing to use, as is saving it for later