# Draw lines on a PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, line, picturebox

My question is related to Stack Overflow question *[Draw lines on a picturebox using mouse clicks in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187524)*, but when the mouse button is up, the drawn line disappears. How do I fix this?

```
private void GainBox_MouseDn(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouse_dn = true;
}

private void GainBox_MouseMv(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Line drawn from lookup table
    if (mouse_dn)
    {
        img = new Bitmap(256, 256);

        //Get the coordinates (x, y) for line from lookup table.

        for (x = x1; x < x2; x++)
            img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);

        //Same for y coordinate
    }
    GainBox.Refresh();
}

private void GainBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouse_dn = false;
}
```

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: If you're trying to draw to a WinForm PictureBox, consult [DrawLines to DrawBeziers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829796/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small complete program that does draw lines based on points (in this case, it follows the mouse). I think you can rework that into what you need.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    // Variable that will hold the point from which to draw the next line
    Point latestPoint;


    private void GainBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // Remember the location where the button was pressed
            latestPoint = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void GainBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            using (Graphics g = GainBox.CreateGraphics())
            {
                // Draw next line and...
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, latestPoint, e.Location);

                // ... Remember the location
                latestPoint = e.Location;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One problem in your solution is that you are drawing on a temporary bitmap, but the image in that bitmap is never transferred to your `PictureBox`. In the solution presented here, there isn't any extra bitmap needed.

Comment: @Fedrick :you are talking about free hand drawing...actually i want to change the shape of the existing curve....when i click some where on picture box,the curve should pass through that point..(playing with input-output curve of the image..)

Comment: @Sisya: the important thing in my answer is not how the points are acquired but how the drawing is performed.

Comment: @Fedrick: yeah..actually i want to drag(not draw) the line all over the picture box,similar to [Image->Adjustments->Curves] in photoshop.

Comment: @Sisya: If you keep a list of `Point` values (or x,y pairs) representing your shape, you can easily iterate over it, using my code to draw a line from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, ..., *n* - 0 to draw the shape. If your question is really about *dragging* the point (as in detecting which point that should be dragged, keeping the point list up-to-date and such) that is quite a different question.

Comment: sorry,its my mistake..its dragging,also after dragging when mouse_up event occurs a small circle or dot should be drawn at that position

Comment: That code draws to a `Graphics` context that will soon be disposed and will not persist. If you want to persist the line on the screen you need to draw in the `Paint` event handler, not `MouseMoved`.

Answer (score 0):

`gainbox.refresh()` should stay inside the `if (mouse_dn)` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use Graphics Object to Drawline

e.g.

```
Graphics gfx = GainBox.CreateGraphics();
gfx.Drawline([Your Parameters here]);
```

Comment: This will draw the line on a local `Graphics` that will soon go out of scope, not to the screen.