# C# DrawLines to DrawBeziers

Tags: c#

I have got this assignment where I have to create points by clicking on the Form. These Points are stored in an Array with which I have to draw Lines.

So far, so good.

But now it asks me to include a checkbox which, when selected, should instantly turn the drawn lines into drawn beziers.

Has anyone got a clue for what I might do?

This is the code I have up till now:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LijnTrekken
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int aantalKliks = 0;
        Point startpunt = new Point();
        Point eindpunt = new Point();

        Point[] points = new Point[20];
        int regelIndex = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            aantalKliks = aantalKliks + 1;
            regelIndex = aantalKliks;

            try
            {
                Point[] bezierPoints = new Point[20]; 

                if (chbGolven.Checked)
                {
                    if (regelIndex < 5)
                    {
                        points[regelIndex] = e.Location;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Pen tekenpen = new Pen(Color.Red);
                        Graphics papier = this.CreateGraphics();
                        papier.DrawBeziers(tekenpen, bezierPoints);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (regelIndex < 20)
                    {
                        points[regelIndex] = e.Location;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Pen tekenpen = new Pen(Color.Red);
                        Graphics papier = this.CreateGraphics();
                        papier.DrawLines(tekenpen, points);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException fe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(fe.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't try to draw to a local `Graphics` as it will get discarded when your method ends. You need to save the points clicked in your `Mouse_Click` event and draw them in your `Paint` event. Consult [How to draw shapes in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991039/).

Answer (score 3):

This code shows how to  REdraw a Lines to BezierLines. Watch DEMO bellow.

```
namespace BeziersLines 
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<PointF> points;
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), 3);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // you can push some start Points here, [ new List<PointF>() {new PointF(0,0), new PointF(100,100), ...} ]
            points = new List<PointF>(); 
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            points.Add(e.Location);
            label1.Text = "Points count: " + points.Count().ToString();
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (points.Count() > 1)
            {
                var g = e.Graphics;
                if (!checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    // Draw Lines
                    g.DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray());
                }
                else
                {
                    // Draw Bezier lines
                    var bezierPoints = points.Take(points.Count - (points.Count - 1) % 3).ToList();
                    g.DrawBeziers(pen, bezierPoints.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukwLF.jpg)

Use readable namings on English next time, its helps people to understand you better, and its a good practice to name it UNDERSTANDABLE for all code readers/users, not only for you.

P.S.

```
var bezierPoints = points.Take(points.Count - (points.Count - 1) % 3).ToList();
```

This line computes the number of points in the array, based on MSD [arctile about DrawBeziers(Pen, PointF[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawbeziers?view=netframework-4.8) cpesificly that line: **"The number of points in the array should be a multiple of 3 plus 1, such as 4, 7, or 10."**

Answer (score 0):

You can populate points array on Form_MouseClick. 
On Form_Paint you will have graphics in PaintEventArgs, you can use it to draw. On Form_Paint you should clear previous painting by filling form rectangle by background color, then you should paint lines or beziers from points array depends on checkbox checked or not.

Comment: Can you share code illustrating your answer? As it stands this answer needs more details.