# Draw line on pictureBox C#

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a desktop stats app for football and I'm trying to make it where the operator can click on an image of a football field and the scrimmage line and first down lines will appear on the field image. Currently I have the field displayed in a pictureBox and I have a clicking event that captures the X location of the cursor (displayed below). The plan is get X and draw line from bottom to top of picture box.

```
public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cursor = Cursor.Position.X;
        int h = pictureBox1.Height;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw lines on a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266745/draw-lines-on-a-picturebox)

Comment: Actually that did. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it solved the problem.

```
        int h = pictureBox1.Height;
        Pen graphPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        PointF pt1D = new PointF();
        PointF pt2D = new PointF();
        pt1D.X = Cursor.Position.X;
        pt1D.Y = 0;
        pt2D.X = Cursor.Position.X;
        pt2D.Y = h;
        g.DrawLine(graphPen, pt1D, pt2D);
```